# Node/Angular App is crashing in all browsers on load?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

My app is crashing in all browsers immediately after typing in a URL. I am using Node on the backend and Angular on the frontend (MEAN stack). I start up my server using `nodemon server.js`, and it tells me it's listening on port 8080.

**Here is the server.js file**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 'extended': 'true' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('App listening on port 8080');
```

**This is my routing**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'public/views/login.html',
            controller: 'userController'
        });
}]);
```

**The controller looks like this:**

```
app.controller('userController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Welcome to my App";
});
```

**And the view looks like this:**

```
<section class="card login">
    <form>
        <div class="textintro">
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
            <p>Log-in to access group finding services</p>
            <p>{{ message }}</p>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </fieldset>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Login</button>
        <p>or <a href="#/register">register</a></p>
    </form>
</section>
```

**File Structure**

```
-node_modules
-public
  --css
  --img
  --js
    ---app.js
  --views
    ---list.html
    ---login.html
  --index.html
-package.json
-server.js
```

**UPDATE**

I used the express router on the `'*'` route and it stopped the page from crashing. I'm still getting a 404 for the static file though: `localhost:8080/public/views/list.html`

Comment: how are you serving `static` resources other than `index.html` ? e.g. `js` , `css`, `login.html`

Comment: I am using this statement: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` ... also see EDIT

Comment: `app.get('*', function(req, res) {` is going to return the index.html for **every request**, including all your templates.  you sated that you have `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` in your server.js, is this ***before*** or ***after*** the `app.get...`?

Comment: the app.use statement is before the app.get

Comment: update your post with full **server.js**

Comment: updated. The page doesn't crash anymore, but it does show a 404 for the template.

Comment: please share the directory structure of app.

Comment: `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public'));` doesn't make sense;  that's not a **file**

Comment: I changed that to `/public/index.html` and updated to using the express router. Page no longer crashes but gives a 404 see update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, all it took was actually reading the documentation for [serving static files with express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

doh ...

I simply had to use:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

And then in my angular app.js file remove the preceding `/public`, so:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/views/list.html',
            controller: 'listController'
        }).
```

The other problem was I had to use the expres router to prevent the page from crashing:

```
var router = express.Router();

router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/index.html"));
});
```

Thanks for the help everyone. Too much tutorial watching and not enough reading documentation.